# How to use chained promises inside firebase functions?

Tags: firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I created a firebase function that updates the like count of an comment or post when a new like document is created.

But it throws an 404 error.

```
exports.updateLikeCount = functions.firestore
    .document('likes')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const likeObj = snap.data();
      if(likeObj.isComment) {
        const { _comment } = likeObj;
        const commentRef = fstore.collection('comments').doc(_comment);

        return commentRef.get()
                .then(doc => {
                    let { likes } = doc.data();
                    ++likes;
                    return commentRef.update({
                      likes
                    });
                });
      }else {
        const { _post } = likeObj;
        const postRef = fstore.collection('posts').doc(_post);

        return postRef.get()
                .then(doc => {
                  let { likes } = doc.data();
                  ++likes;
                  return postRef.update({
                    likes
                  });
                });
      }
    });
```

NOTE: 
_post and _comment are post ID and comment ID respectively

Comment: Can you add the code where you initialize `fstore`?

Comment: Can you show us the full network error?

Comment: @JenPerson Yes const fstore = firebase.firestore();

Comment: @camden_kid where can i get that ? Do you mean the logs in firebase console.

Comment: Ok well without the import information I can't be sure, but it looks like you're using the client-side Firestore SDK instead of the Admin one. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk) show you how to install and initialize the Admin SDK to use it

Comment: @JenPerson Nope I am using the admin sdk... The problem is return chained promises the function works when I return only one of them. So that was the root of my question.